# C program doesn't wait for user input with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to C and this is my TicTacToe for first C project. For that, I setup a simple process for user where to choose X or O. But it doesn't seem to work for reason. Here it continues to the if statements and goes into infinite loop cause it didn't wait for user input.

I've gone through similar forums about this exact question but I was unable to get an answer that fixed my problem. Also, feedbacks about the code are much appreciated because I do want to improve my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char checks_player;
    int is_input_valid = 0;

    while(is_input_valid == 0)
    {
        printf("What do you want to choose? (X/O) ");
        scanf(" %c",checks_player);
        if(checks_player == 'x')
        {
            checks_player = 'X';
            is_input_valid = 1;
        }
        else if(checks_player == 'o')
        {
            checks_player = 'O';
            is_input_valid=1;
        }
        else if((checks_player == 'O')|| (checks_player == 'X'))
        {
            is_input_valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Input!!\nTry Again.\n\n");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: checking compiler warnings is a good idea and tells you exactly the issue

Comment: surprisingly, compiler didn't warn be about absence of pointer.

Comment: because you need to enable warnings

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer to `scanf`. Instead of this:

```
        scanf(" %c",checks_player);
```

Use this:

```
        scanf(" %c", &checks_player);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I am ashamed of doing such a basic mistake.